# Having trouble with font types in python Turtle

Tags: fonts, python-turtle

I began working on an assessment using python Turtle.
Everything else has worked the way I expected it to except the font types, I've looked through mulitple websites and tried different ways of inputting the code but it isnt working, could somebody please help?

The code issue:

```
write("text is here", font=("Courier New", 25, "bold"))
```

i have also tried the words `"Courier"`, `"couriernew"`, `"Courier New"` and `"courier new"`.

everything else in the line of code will work except the font, it is always default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it isn't with the font. You're supposed to do `turtle.write()`, not just `write()`. I've tried it and it only works when I do `turtle.write()`. I don't know exactly why it says that the font is the problem, but there's your answer, I guess.